# 2 кастомные ячейки в tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как в методе cellForRowAtIndexPath написать две ячейки, которые будут переиспользоваться ?

Comment: так же как и одну, но сделать два разных reuse idnetifiers и использовать необходимый по ситуации

Comment: у вас 5 вопросов кстати с непринятыми ответами, вы б может уделили 5 минут